How should I control a 24VDC solenoid using 12VDC relay and separate power supplies?
This would be part of a pipe organ control system. While most of the organ components (e.g. air valves under pipes) are 12VDC, the solenoids to pull or push some items on or off can operate on either 12VDC or 24VDC. Their design is such that they’re more efficient at 24VDC.
How would one power the 24VDC solenoids with a 24VDC power supply, but control them with the 12VDC relay system which has its own 12VDC power supply which powers everything else in the organ? A schematic would help.

Not enough information. Are there spare contacts available on the existing 12 V relays?

"So how would one power the 24VDC solenoids with a 24VDC power supply, but control them with the 12VDC relay system" Connect them to the relay contacts and off you go? The relay coil voltage doesn't matter for the stuff you connect on the relay contacts. Adding a freewheel diode across the solenoid is a very good idea however. As is adding one across the relay coil.

What does the "efficient" in "more efficient at 24VDC" mean? Are they more effective at 24 V, for example, acting a little bit faster?

Relay contacts are voltage-agnostic within their ratings.
You can use a 12V-coil relay to switch a 6V, 12V or 24V solenoid.
However if the same contacts on one relay are required to switch multiple solenoids of multiple voltages then it might be a bit more complex.

Here is the basic setup for one relay controlling one relay.  This answer assumes you have things like contact ratings and coil currents under control.
GND2 is the return for the 24 V supply.  It can be tied to the 12 Vdc GND or not - the circuit works either way.


I don't get it. What's the purpose of the 24V relay? Why can't you power the solenoid directly through the 12V relay contacts?

What software was this drawn in?

As noted by @Spehro, the coil rating has no relevance for what you connect on the relay contacts. A typical standard relay will have a coil rating and then a contact rating, the latter being something like 230VAC/30VDC 8A maximum ratings.
So if you have a 12V relay you are already ready to go. Just add freewheel diodes across any inductive load since otherwise reverse EMF might break things.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Regarding grounds, consider that the solenoid(s) might draw some Ampere and if you have a whole bunch of these you should not ground them to whatever PCB you have there but rather to where that PCB takes it supply ground from (some PSU?). Dimension cables accordingly.
